# Python: Import directory from a file inside that directory

Tags: python, import

I'm sorry if the title is confusing since English is not my first language. What I have trouble is running a python script that calls import of its own directory. The folder structure is like this:

```
MyProject 
    |--Utils
          |-- util
          |     |-- __init__.py
          |     |-- run.py
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- test.py
```

And the code of test.py is as following

```
import Utils.util

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Do something
```

When running test.py, I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utils'
```

Is there anyway to call import that's suitable for this folder structure? If it's possible, someone can please help me naming this problem for better searches?

I have tried create a new script in the root folder which runs normally. However, what if I want to store testing code like test.py in modular folders, the import command is not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Utils'" occurs because Python doesn't automatically search for modules within subdirectories unless they are treated as packages.

```
from .util import
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs very much. It have helped me finding out that the folder is structured for exporting pip packages, from this clue I found how to directly run the setup and run the script without calling pip install

Answer (score 2):

Your project structure is not formatted correctly,
but I think this should work in your case:

```
from .Utils import utils
```